# Should I pass the same extracted character to std::cin.putback() frm the last read?

Tags: c++

In C++ primer 5th edition about Unformatted IO operations:

> putback is a more specialized version of unget: It returns the last value read from the stream but takes an argument that must be the same as the one that was last read.

So I've implemented this program that extracts each following character from the input buffer, checks if it is a `'*'` then replaces it back with the character `'$'` in the input stream buffer. Otherwise returns back the last read character to the Input buffer then read it, sum it to a string:

```
std::string str;

while( std::cin.peek() != EOF){
    if( std::cin.get() == '*')
        std::cin.putback('$');
    else
        std::cin.unget();
    str += std::cin.get();
}
```

Input:

```
Hello***There!
```

output:

```
Hello$$$there!
```

- The program looks to work fine but in my case I extract '`*`' as the last character read but calling `std::cin.putback('$')` in which case they are not identical characters. And in the text above it is said that "...takes an argument that must be the same as the one that was last read."

So could you please clarify it?

Comment: Is it allowed yes. Does that break the contract yesish. Other people using your object as a stream will not get the expected output. The reason that `putback()` takes a character is to allow efficient implementation of the buffer (it does not need to remember the character after it has released it). By providing the interface like this it means certain constraints can be lifted from the implementation (like remembering the last character).

Comment: @MartinYork: Would you mind to add an answer?

Comment: This would be a lot less clunky if you just did a `switch` on the character you got and did substitutions where necessary.

Comment: @MartinYork: But in cppreference it passes to it a different character other than the last read one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback